# How to replace a part of a string with zeroes?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to replace part of a string with zeroes. To be more specific third to sixth position should be zeroes.

Example:
I have `123456789`
I need `120000789`

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: What if the original string is shorter than 6 characters,  e.g. `'12345'`?

Comment: Is the length of the string fixed at 9 characters?

Comment: String is always longer than 6 characters. 9 long in 100% of the cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way in Oracle is probably to just reconstruct the string:

```
select substr(col, 1, 2) || '0000' || substr(col, 7)
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon that is an incredibly quick answer :)) And it works like a charm!

Comment: If not the simplest, it is almost certainly the most efficient. And it is simple enough that any further simplification, at the cost of lower efficiency, is hard to justify.

Comment: (Note: I edited the answer to change a `+` to `||`; and, more importantly, to remove the last argument in the second call to `SUBSTR`. This way the masking will work for all inputs of length six or greater, without requiring prior knowledge that all the strings will be of length exactly 9.)

Answer (score 1):

```
select rpad(substr('&str',1,2),6,'0')||substr('&str',7,3) from dual;
```